# React Native Notification not receiving when app is in the background

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Notifications are working fine with iOS. But in Android, background notifications are not received. Since it is a data-only notification I am using some third-party plugins to show it as local notification.

```
react-native - 0.68.2
react-native-marketingcloudsdk - 0.75.2
```

Can anyone help me with react-native-marketingcloudsdk android?

I think I am doing it in the wrong way. There is no proper documentation for this.

Comment: Do you have an open support case?

Comment: No i don't have

Comment: Start there. Always.